# Family tree hierarchy with Pure CSS using divs

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a family tree, I have a problem with connecting lines, I managed to do first row, with oblique lines, however when I apply the same to the second row the oblique lines disappears. Any ideas how to fix it?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: url(../img/bg.jpeg);
}

img {
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 13px #222;
  border: solid 3px #606f46;
}

span {
  background: #beebb3;
  border-color: #606f46;
  border-radius: 30px 0 30px 0;
  padding: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  margin-top: 5px;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 13px #222;
}

h1 {
  /* width: 580px; */
  font-family: 'My Soul', cursive;
  font-size: 3.6rem;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

#no1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 190px;
  line-height: 60px;
  margin: auto;
}

#container1 {
  width: 580px;
  font-family: verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}

#container a {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #beebb3;
}

#no1 a {
  height: 60px;
}

#no2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 190px;
  line-height: 60px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 9px;
}

#no3 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 190px;
  line-height: 60px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 9px;
}

#no4 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 190px;
  line-height: 60px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 9px;
}

.container2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-left: 240px;
}

.container3 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-left: 35px;
  margin-right: 150px;
}

.container4 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-right: 240px;
}

.tree {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 10px;
}

.level1 {
  display: flex;
  height: 3px;
  width: 18%;
  border-style: hidden solid solid solid;
  margin: auto;
  border-width: thick;
}

.oblique1 {

  width: 23%;
  transform: rotate(-30deg);
  border-width: thick;
  border-style: hidden hidden solid hidden;
}

.oblique2 {

  width: 23%;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  border-width: thick;
  border-style: hidden hidden solid hidden;
}

.line_container1 {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 200px;
  margin-top: 17px;
}

.line_container2 {
  display: flex;
}

.images {
  background-color: white;
}

.container22 {
  width: 700px;
  font-family: verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Family Tree</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./img/family-tree.png" type="image/x-icon">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=My+Soul&family=Sacramento&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container1">
    <h1>___Family Tree___</h1>
    <div id="no1">
      <div class="tree">
        <img src="https://entertainment.time.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2013/05/fictioninfluence_list_homersimpson.jpg">
        <span>
          Homer Simpson
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="tree">
        <img class="images" src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/theultimatesimpsons/images/0/0f/Marge-Simpson-icon.png/revision/latest?cb=20180210061653">
        <span>
          Marge Simpson
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="level1"></div>
    <div class="line_container1">
      <div class="oblique1"></div>
      <div class="oblique2"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container22">


    <div id="no2">
      <div class="tree">
        <img src="https://openpsychometrics.org/tests/characters/test-resources/pics/S/2.jpg">
        <span>
          Bart Simpson
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="tree">
        <img src="https://mella187.github.io/Cartoon-Hero/img/lisa-avatar.jpg">
        <span>
          Lisa Simpson
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="tree">
        <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/e5/4a/bc/e54abc44b68d6b2770696b789b20dafa.png">
        <span>
          Abraham Simpson
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="tree">
        <img class="images" src="https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/jonathan-rey/simpsons/256/Maggie-Simpson-icon.png">
        <span>
          Maggie Simpson
        </span>
      </div>

    </div>

<div class="line_container2">


      <div class="level1">
        <div class="line_container1">
          <div class="oblique1"></div>
          <div class="oblique2"></div>
      </div>

      </div>
      <div class="level1">
        <div class="line_container1">
          <div class="oblique1"></div>
          <div class="oblique2"></div>
      </div>

</div>
    </div>
    </div>


    <div id="no3">
      <div class="tree">
        <img class="images" src="https://cdn.quotesgram.com/img/7/98/1464708000-Ned_Flanders.png">
        <span>
          Ned Flanders
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="tree">
        <img class="images" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/b7/4f/ae/b74faea8de35d22b703b6ae32f891a92.png">
        <span>
          Elizabeth Hoover
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="tree">
        <img class="images" src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/p__/images/3/3a/Seymour_Skinner.png/revision/latest/top-crop/width/360/height/360?cb=20200804144332&path-prefix=protagonist">
        <span>
          Seymour Skinner
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="tree">
        <img class="images" src="https://www.personality-database.com/profile_images/20160.png">
        <span> Edna Krabappel
        </span>
      </div>


      <div class="tree">
        <img class="images" src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/p__/images/b/b4/Barnild_Gumble.png/revision/latest/top-crop/width/360/height/360?cb=20160402113506&path-prefix=protagonist">
        <span>
          Barney Gumble
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="tree">
        <img class="images" src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/simpsons/images/d/d5/Patty_Bouvier1.png/revision/latest/top-crop/width/360/height/360?cb=20201222215313">
        <span>
          Selma Bouvier
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="no4">
      <div class="container2">
        <div class="tree">
          <img src="https://www.canncentral.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/Kent_Brockman-Cannabis-1.jpg">
          <span>
            Kent Brockman
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="tree">
          <img src="https://untappd.akamaized.net/site/beer_logos_hd/beer-1158277_7220b_hd.jpeg">
          <span>
            Mayor Quimby
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="tree">
          <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/474x/8e/a1/2b/8ea12bd79870a03994fbf65f63baaa92--school-pictures-sideshow.jpg">
          <span>
            Sideshow Bob
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container3">
        <div class="tree">
          <img class="images" src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/p__/images/8/81/Wiggum_with_coffee.png/revision/latest/top-crop/width/360/height/360?cb=20160322214733&path-prefix=protagonist">
          <span>
            Clancy Wiggum
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container4">
        <div class="tree">
          <img src="https://www.kindpng.com/picc/m/394-3940977_los-simpson-nikki-mckenna-hd-png-download.png">
          <span>
            Nikki McKenna
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="tree">
          <img src="https://topicimages.mrowl.com/large/owl/thesimpsons/characters/milhousevanhou_1.jpg">
          <span>
            Milhouse Van Houten
          </span>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The reason why the oblique bars disappears is for their width. It's set as percentage, but the container has 0px width, so they won't appear. However, that isn't the only problem, it would probably benefit to rethink the way you're creating those oblique lines and positioning them

Comment: Do you have any suggestions how I can make it, please?

Comment: I know it's not, it's not a problem :D I just had the goal to fill the images, with whatever of them, so I just put Simpsons characters, they don't actually need to be relatives)) lol

Comment: A cleaner way might be using svgs or images. They're not terribly hard to do with inkscape/gimp. You could do it with dom elements, but it will be a bit harder

Comment: The goal is to do them with divs, not with drawings

Comment: try editing this code and see https://jsfiddle.net/2oqha40z/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, try using more [semantic](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Semantics) tags, in the example `<main>`, `<section>`, `<figure>`, and `<figcaption>` were used instead of `<div>` and `<span>`. It doesn't make the HTML invalid if you only use `<div>` and `<span>` but it'll hold less meaning and there's a greater chance of errors being overlooked.

`display: table/table-row/table-cell` was assigned to `<main>/<section>/<figure>` respectively. Using `<table>` for layout is highly discouraged, but using other tags that behave like a `<table>` is ok. In the example, the table-like layout is 3 rows (one row for each generation) and 5 columns. The only borders that are visible are actually the lines that connect "leaves" to each other (as spouses or siblings). For demonstration purposes I added a little JavaScript -- just click anywhere to toggle the invisible borders off and on.

***Further details are commented in the example below***

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Family Tree</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./img/family-tree.png" type="image/x-icon">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=My+Soul&family=Sacramento&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  /* 
  Default font-size is referenced here
  Any rem used elsewhere will be directly referenced to this font-size
  Default is dynamic -- whenever window is resized, it will adjust to width
  if it is bigger than height and vice versa.
  In turn, anything in rem will also adjust 2.5vmax === 1rem
  */
  html {
    font: 2.5vmax/1.5 Sacramento;
  }

  body {
    padding-bottom: 12px;
  }

  /*
  As a <table>, main will adhere to what each column is in width. this 
  behavior allows it to scale to the width of viewport (window).
  */
  main {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    background: transparent;
  }

  h1 {
    display: table-caption;
    margin: 10px auto;
    padding-top: 10px;
    font-family: 'My Soul';
    font-size: 2.6rem;
    text-align: center;
  }

  /*
  As a <tr>, it automatically holds it's children in a solid row
  */
  section {
    display: table-row;
    background: transparent;
  }

  /*
  As a <td>, padding, vertical-align, width, etc are handled so each one is 
  uniformly the same height and content is evenly positioned.
  */
  figure,
  .cell {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 20%;
    background: transparent;
  }

  img {
    width: 7.5em;
    height: 7.5rem;
    border: solid 3px #606f46;
    border-radius: 100%;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 13px #222;
  }

  figcaption {
    width: min-content;
    margin-top: -5px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #606f46;
    border-radius: 30px 0 30px 0;
    background: #beebb3;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 13px #222;
    text-align: center;
  }

  /*
  These tags act as empty cells and are placed in-between each "leaf". The majority
  of the lines are from their visible borders.
  */
  .cell b {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
    min-height: 4rem;
  }

  /*
  Applied to .cell between parents -- it connects them
  */
  .parents b {
    border-top: 6px solid black;
  }

  /*
  Applied to .cell between parents -- it adds a descendant line
  */
  .parents b::before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 45%;
    width: 1px;
    height: 8.25rem;
    border: 3px solid black;
    background: black;
  }

  /*
  Applied to .cell between siblings and the <figure> of any middle children 
  -- it connects them
  */
  .siblings {
    border-top: 6px solid black;
  }

  /*
  Applied to .cell to the right of the oldest child and to the left of the 
  youngest child
  */
  .elder,
  .baby {
    position: relative;
  }

  /*
  Applied to .cell to the right of the oldest child and adds an arrow 
  */
  .elder::before {
    content: '\002b9f';
    position: absolute;
    left: -1rem;
    top: -1.5rem;
    font-size: 2rem;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }

  /*
  Applied to the .cell to the left of the youngest child and adds an arrow
  */
  .baby::after {
    content: '\002b9f';
    position: absolute;
    right: -1rem;
    top: -1.5rem;
    font-size: 2rem;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }

  /*
  For demonstration purposes
  Styles showLayout(e) toggles on every click (optional)
  */
  .show .cell b {
    outline: 3px dotted rgba(255, 0, 50, 0.6);
  }

  .show .cell {
    outline: 2px dashed rgba(129, 129, 129, 0.4);
  }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <h1>___Simpson&nbsp;Family&nbsp;Tree___</h1>
    <section>
      <div class='cell'><b></b></div>
      <figure>
        <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/e5/4a/bc/e54abc44b68d6b2770696b789b20dafa.png">
        <figcaption>Abraham Simpson</figcaption>
      </figure>
      <div class='cell parents'><b></b></div>
      <figure>
        <img src='https://comicvine.gamespot.com/a/uploads/square_tiny/11/111746/6556151-mona_simpson.png'>
        <figcaption>Mona Simpson</figcaption>
      </figure>
      <div class='cell'><b></b></div>
    </section>
    <section>
      <div class='cell'><b></b></div>
      <div class='cell'><b></b></div>
      <figure>
        <img src="https://entertainment.time.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2013/05/fictioninfluence_list_homersimpson.jpg">
        <figcaption> Homer Simpson </figcaption>
      </figure>
      <div class='cell parents'><b></b></div>
      <figure>
        <img src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/theultimatesimpsons/images/0/0f/Marge-Simpson-icon.png">
        <figcaption>Marge Simpson</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </section>
    <section>
      <figure>
        <img src="https://openpsychometrics.org/tests/characters/test-resources/pics/S/2.jpg">
        <figcaption>Bart Simpson</figcaption>
      </figure>
      <div class='cell siblings elder'><b></b></div>
      <figure class='siblings'>
        <img src="https://mella187.github.io/Cartoon-Hero/img/lisa-avatar.jpg">
        <figcaption>Lisa Simpson</figcaption>
      </figure>
      <div class='cell siblings baby'><b></b></div>
      <figure>
        <img src="https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/jonathan-rey/simpsons/256/Maggie-Simpson-icon.png">
        <figcaption>Maggie Simpson</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </section>
  </main>
  <script>
  /*
  For demonstration purposes - it exposes the borders (optional)
  */
  document.querySelector('main').onclick = showLayout;

  function showLayout(e) {
    this.classList.toggle('show');
  }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```